# installing pcl / linking error

Tags: arm, vtk, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to realize a asus Xtion sensor connected to a Pandaboard. I'm using  Ubuntu10.10 server together with ROS. When I want to compile PCL I get the following error. Some mismatch with libmysqlclient and libvtk? I don't know what to do from here, any help is appreciated.

```
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
 No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cpp_common [PASS] [ 4.86 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_traits [PASS] [ 5.73 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostime [PASS] [ 5.87 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization [PASS] [ 5.32 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs [PASS] [ 25.74 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp [PASS] [ 5.99 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole [PASS] [ 6.01 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs [PASS] [ 5.75 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph [PASS] [ 3.92 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy [PASS] [ 3.82 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosparam [PASS] [ 6.85 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp [PASS] [ 14.17 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmaster [PASS] [ 3.88 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> eigen [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< eigen [PASS] [ 0.05 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cminpack [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cminpack [PASS] [ 0.08 seconds ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> flann [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< flann [PASS] [ 0.07 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosout [PASS] [ 4.16 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslaunch  No Makefile in package roslaunch
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostest [PASS] [ 5.58 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< topic_tools [PASS] [ 14.21 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbag [PASS] [ 7.26 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbagmigration [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbagmigration  No Makefile in package rosbagmigration
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs [PASS] [ 18.90 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs [PASS] [ 18.10 seconds ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesl: 37.8 sec ]               [ 1 Active 30/31 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
  cd /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/surface /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/surface /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/surface/CMakeFiles/pcl_surface.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
  make -f surface/CMakeFiles/pcl_surface.dir/build.make surface/CMakeFiles/pcl_surface.dir/build
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
  make[3]: Nothing to be done for `surface/CMakeFiles/pcl_surface.dir/build'.
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
  /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/CMakeFiles  84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91
  [ 83%] Built target pcl_surface
  make -f visualization/CMakeFiles/pcl_visualization.dir/build.make visualization/CMakeFiles/pcl_visualization.dir/depend
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
  cd /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/visualization /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/visualization /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/visualization/CMakeFiles/pcl_visualization.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
  make -f visualization/CMakeFiles/pcl_visualization.dir/build.make visualization/CMakeFiles/pcl_visualization.dir/build
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
  make[3]: Nothing to be done for `visualization/CMakeFiles/pcl_visualization.dir/build'.
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
  /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/CMakeFiles  92 93 94 95 96 97 98
  [ 90%] Built target pcl_visualization
  make -f visualization/test/CMakeFiles/demo_shapes.dir/build.make visualization/test/CMakeFiles/demo_shapes.dir/depend
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
  cd /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/visualization/test /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/visualization/test /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/visualization/test/CMakeFiles/demo_shapes.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
  make -f visualization/test/CMakeFiles/demo_shapes.dir/build.make visualization/test/CMakeFiles/demo_shapes.dir/build
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
  Linking CXX executable demo_shapes
  cd /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/visualization/test && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/demo_shapes.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
  /usr/bin/c++     -Wno-deprecated -O3 -DNDEBUG     CMakeFiles/demo_shapes.dir/test_shapes.cpp.o  -o demo_shapes -rdynamic -L/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/messages/std_msgs/lib -L/home/panda/ros_workspace/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/lib -L/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_serialization/lib -L/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/utilities/cpp_common/lib -L/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/utilities/rostime/lib -L/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/lib -L/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/lib -L/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/lib -L/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/tools/rosbag/lib -L/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/tools/topic_tools/lib -L/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/lib -L/usr/lib/vtk-5.6 ../../common/libpcl_common.so.1.1.1 ../../io/libpcl_io.so.1.1.1 ../../kdtree/libpcl_kdtree.so.1.1.1 ../../range_image/libpcl_range_image.so.1.1.1 ../libpcl_visualization.so.1.1.1 ../../io/libpcl_io.so.1.1.1 -lOpenNI ../../kdtree/libpcl_kdtree.so.1.1.1 /home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/flann/lib/libflann.so ../../range_image/libpcl_range_image.so.1.1.1 ../../common/libpcl_common.so.1.1.1 -lsensor_msgs -lroscpp_serialization -lrosconsole -lgomp -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_date_time-mt -lvtkWidgets -lvtkHybrid -lvtkParallel -lvtkRendering -lvtkGraphics -lvtkverdict -lvtkImaging -lvtkftgl -lfreetype -lQtGui -lQtCore -lgl2ps -lXt -lX11 -lvtkIO -lpq -lmysqlclient -lvtkFiltering -lvtkDICOMParser -lnetcdf_c++ -lpng -lvtkmetaio -lz -lvtksqlite -ljpeg -ltiff -lexpat -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lswscale -lVPIC -lCosmo -lvtkCommon -lm -lpthread -lvtksys -ldl /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libopen-rte.so /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so -ldl -lnsl -lutil -lm -ldl -lnsl -lutil -lm /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi_cxx.so -lvtkexoIIc -lnetcdf -lGL -Wl,-rpath,/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/messages/std_msgs/lib:/home/panda/ros_workspace/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/lib:/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_serialization/lib:/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/utilities/cpp_common/lib:/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/utilities/rostime/lib:/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/lib:/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/lib:/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/tools/rosconsole/lib:/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/tools/rosbag/lib:/home/panda/ros_workspace/ros_comm/tools/topic_tools/lib:/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/lib:/usr/lib/vtk-5.6:/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/common:/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/io:/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/kdtree:/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/range_image:/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build/visualization:/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/flann/lib:/usr/lib/openmpi/lib
  /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libvtkIO.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2lz@libmysqlclient_16'
  /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libvtkIO.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_f2lz@libmysqlclient_16'
  /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libvtkIO.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_f2ulz@libmysqlclient_16'
  /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/../../../../lib/libvtkIO.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2ulz@libmysqlclient_16'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [visualization/test/demo_shapes] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
  make[2]: *** [visualization/test/CMakeFiles/demo_shapes.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/panda/ros_workspace/perception_pcl/pcl/build/pcl/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package pcl written to: Active 30/31 Complete ]
[ rosmake ]    /home/panda/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120625-120146/pcl/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pcl [FAIL] [ 37.88 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pcl.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 31 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/panda/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120625-120146
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your graphic card is supported.

And then, go to the official web and download the software, follow correctly the instructions.
[PCL Downloads](http://pointclouds.org/downloads/)
Take a look in ROS official web
[PCL ROS](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl)

At present I am working with PCL and MS Kinect, all is working correctly in Windows ;)
But previously I had installed PCL on Linux

I can say I had problems, but I downloaded the latest drivers of my graphic Card and works fine.

Happy code!